# Not able to see the choices of selectInput and get its count in shinyApp

Tags: r, input, shiny, radio-button, dt

I'm building a shinyApp on mtcars data. I'm facing a problem in counting values and displaying choices  of **cyl button**. 
When **all** is selected in **disp button**, then *cyl filter* shows accurate count and it displays the choices as well. If values other than *all* are selected in *disp* then **cyl will give 0 count and won't show any choices**.
Can somebody please have a look at my codes. I shall be extremely grateful.

library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(dplyr) 
    library(shinythemes) 
    library(htmlwidgets) 
    library(shinyWidgets) 
    library(shinydashboard)

```
data_table<-mtcars    
data_table$hp<-NULL
data_table$qsec<-NULL
data_table$drat<-NULL

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("vs_selector"),
      uiOutput("carb_selector"),
      uiOutput("gear_selector"),
      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_gear"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_cyl")),


    mainPanel(

      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') 

    )

  ))




#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$vs_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "vs",
                label = "vs:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(data_table$vs)),
                selected = c(0))

  })

  output$carb_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs)

    available0 <- data_table[c(data_table$vs %in% input$vs ), "carb"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "carb", 
      label = "carb:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available0))),
      selected = c('4'))

  })


  output$gear_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs, input$carb)

    available <- data_table[["gear"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]
    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      available <- available[data_table$carb %in% input$carb]
    }

    selectInput(
      inputId = "gear", 
      label = "gear:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = c('4'))

  })



  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs, input$carb, input$gear)

    available <- data_table[["cyl"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]




    selectInput(
      inputId = "cyl", 
      label = "cyl:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = c('6', '8', '4'))

  })





  output$count_gear <- renderValueBox({


    valueBox(
      value = length(unique(thedata()[["gear"]])), 


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of gear values" ))   

  })




  output$count_cyl <- renderValueBox({

    #req(input$vs, input$carb, input$gear)

    #available <- data_table[["cyl"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]





    valueBox(


      # if("All" %in% input$cyl) {
      #    value = "All"
      #  } else(value = length(unique(input$cyl))),

      value = length(unique(thedata()[["cyl"]])),

      subtitle = sprintf("Number of cyl values" ))   

  })







  thedata <- reactive({

    req(input$gear, input$vs, input$carb, input$cyl)

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs,]

    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$carb %in% input$carb,]
    }

    if(! "All" %in% input$gear){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$gear %in% input$gear,]
    }


    if(! "All" %in% input$cyl){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]
    }


    data_table

  })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( {     

      thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()

    })

  })

}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to find ways to optimize your code as it does a lot of simpler things in a complicated way. Anyways, for this question it's been resolved.

- Changed your filtering and `if` condition
- Changed the count by using the `input$cyl` value

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)


data_table<-mtcars    

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("vs_selector"),
      uiOutput("carb_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),
      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_disp"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_cyl")),


    mainPanel(

      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') 

    )

  ))




#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$vs_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "vs",
                label = "vs:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(data_table$vs)),
                selected = c(0,1))

  })

  output$carb_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs)

    available0 <- data_table[c(data_table$vs %in% input$vs ), "carb"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "carb", 
      label = "carb:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available0))),
      selected = 'All')

  })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs, input$carb)

    available <- data_table[["disp"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]
    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      available <- available[data_table$carb %in% input$carb]
    }

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = c(160,108, 258, 360))

  })



  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

     req(input$vs, input$carb, input$disp)

     available <- data_table[["cyl"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]




    selectInput(
      inputId = "cyl", 
      label = "cyl:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All')

  })





  output$count_disp <- renderValueBox({


    valueBox(
      value = length(unique(thedata()[["disp"]])), 


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of disp values" ))   

  })




  output$count_cyl <- renderValueBox({

    #req(input$vs, input$carb, input$disp)

    #available <- data_table[["cyl"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]





    valueBox(


     # if("All" %in% input$cyl) {
    #    value = "All"
    #  } else(value = length(unique(input$cyl))),

     value = length(unique(thedata()[["cyl"]])),

      subtitle = sprintf("Number of cyl values" ))   

  })







  thedata <- reactive({

    req(input$disp, input$vs, input$carb, input$cyl)

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs,]

    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$carb %in% input$carb,]
    }

    if(! "All" %in% input$disp){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }


    if(! "All" %in% input$cyl){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]
    }


    data_table

  })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( {     

      thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()

    })

  })

}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Update:

Count of cylinders is taken from the output data by selecting the column.

Comment: Thanks mate, but still there's a problem coming up. You can see there's *All* written  for number of cyl values instead of a number as that shown for number of *disp* values. Could you please have a look again

Comment: @Doctor That means, you want 3 in there?

Comment: i want the count of unique values present in *cyl* when i select values from *vs, carb, disp*. Same like disp counts are shown in according with its above filtered inputs

Comment: Do you want the count of unique cyl values or the count of number of rows?

Comment: Count of cyl values mate

Comment: There's a problem coming up. Pls select vs=1, carb=1, and the number of values coming in **disp** would be wrong

Comment: Updated the code - ideally that was not part of the current question.

Comment: umm still not right . Please select vs=0, carb=2 and see the values coming up in disp. They will be wrong

Comment: I updated my codes. As you can see that 8,4 is selected in cyl filter but its not appearing in the table. Thats a problem. Secondly NA is coming as choice in gear filter as well which shouldn't be coming. Can you pls lookover again